# Sound support Ubuntu 14.04 vs Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, sound, lubuntu, hdmi

I have Intel 1.6Ghz Atom so it's not powerful enough for Ubuntu 14.04 I wanted to use Lubuntu 14.04 but it's not giving me sound on my HDMI. It does work on headphone Card 0, Device 0.

When in Lubuntu the result compare the Ubuntu is Device 3 shows subdevice 0/1.
So even doing a sound test HDMI does not output. So the other solution for people who posted here on editing asound.conf doesn't help.

Is the sound driver somehow different from Ubuntu 14.04 vs Lubuntu 14.04?

```
------- From Ubuntu 14.04 ----
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 0: ALC888 Analog [ALC888 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 1: ALC888 Digital [ALC888 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Drivers are in the kernel so Lubuntu vs Ubuntu should not make a difference. Start here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

Comment: The drivers are the same but the GUI tools to configure sound are different for LXDE than unity.

Comment: I always struggle with sound on Lubuntu but it's easy peasy on Ubuntu.  I would love to know the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

For some users IF you want an easy way to switch to hdmi as the sound device. Install the pavucontrol package may use up a little more resoucres than lubuntu out of the box to change the sound output device and on the volume control in the panel you can select your hdmi output if you had a monitor with pictures. Although sometimes if you misconfigure asound.conf that can break sound.